# Props are undefined when passing from Parent Class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

(Disclaimer - I am a noob)
I have come across an issue while trying to implement Capacitors Device API into my Ionic React project. The props (mobileInfo) being passed to my DeviceView function are undefined. Can anybody possibly explain why that is?

*******DeviceContainer.tsx********

```
import {Component} from "react";
import DeviceView from './DeviceView';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Device } from '@capacitor/device';

export class DeviceContainer extends React.Component {

    
    state: { mobileInfo: string }
    

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)

        this.state =
        {
            mobileInfo: "",

        }
    }
    async getDeviceInfo (){

        const info =  Device.getInfo();

        this.setState({

            mobileInfo: JSON.stringify(info)
            

        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDeviceInfo();
    }

    render() {

        return (
            
            <DeviceView
                mobileInfo={this.state.mobileInfo}
            />

        )
    }
}
export default DeviceContainer;
```

*******DeviceView.tsx********

```
import React from 'react'
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import DeviceContainer from './DeviceContainer'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

const DeviceView = ({ mobileInfo }: any) => {

    if (mobileInfo !== undefined) {
        console.log('prop was passed');
      } else {
        console.log('prop was NOT passed');
      }

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>Device Info</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Mobile Info: {mobileInfo}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    )
}

export default DeviceView;
```

I am expecting the DeviceView.tsx to display the users device info using the mobileInfo prop.

Comment: Are you sure that `Device.getInfo();` is not returning `undefined`?

Comment: @Tbagt47 you can `console.log` right before setState in `getDeviceInfo`

Comment: @mikenlanggio Thank you. I just logged it to the console and it prints an object that lists my device info (https://snipboard.io/ChYcmV.jpg) . All Device methods work as well. However, the props {mobileInfo} being passed to DeviceView.tsx is still undefined.

Comment: @TristanLux see my answer below. Hope it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `await` `Device.getInfo()`, because this method is async.

```
async getDeviceInfo(){

    const info = await Device.getInfo();
    console.log('---info', info)
    this.setState({
        mobileInfo: JSON.stringify(info)
    });
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getDeviceInfo();
}
```